# winApi 32 icons definition

Tags: winapi

I wanted to ask about winApi 32 custom icons creation. When I define icon in `recource.h`:

`#define IDI_MYICON 1`

What does that number, in this case `1` mean?
And what about `IDI` is it just a standard or it actually means something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1` is the value, `IDI_MYICON` is just a placeholder for the `1`

`IDI` is an prefix and stands for `An Icon or bitmap resource`

see this [list](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Resource_Script_Reference#Identifiers)

Normaly ResourceID's get assigned automaticly by Visual Studio (or other IDE).

So you could use `IDI_MYICON` instead of using the `1` in your code.

Comment: So, do I assign anything I want ?

Answer (score 2):

Icons are stored in the resource section of the PE file when it is built. The "1" is the resource identifier for that icon. It doesn't have to be "1" but each icon must have a unique identifier. It's just easier to start at 1 and go up.

IDI is a Microsoft convention to identify an Icon resource. You could actually name it anything you want but sticking with convention will lead to less confusion.